# .MDF file not connect to my project

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, mdf

I have a `.mdf` file in my system. I want to connect that file to my project. But it show connect problem. How can I connect that `.mdf` to my C# project.

This is my code:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\Employee.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1000 [Id],[Emp_name],[Joining_date],[Salary],[Email],[Phone]FROM [Employee].[dbo].[Employeedetail]", connection);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["Id"]));
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

This is the error display on my screen:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Most likely you just don't have SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB installed (that what the connection string is trying to load). Go to `Start Menu > SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager` - what kind of entries do you have in the "SQL Server Services" tab?

Comment: I have nothing. that's tab showing shutting down